# useTexture in react-three-fibre not showing image

Tags: textures, react-three-fiber

The code of App.js is as follows:

```
import './App.css';
import { useRef, Suspense} from 'react';
import {Canvas, useFrame} from '@react-three/fiber';
import { useTexture } from '@react-three/drei';
import img1 from './image/20211008_203906.jpg';

function Box(){
  const props=useTexture({
    texture_1: img1,
    texture_2: img1,
    texture_3: img1,
    texture_4: img1,
    texture_5: img1,
    texture_6: img1
  });
  const mesh=useRef();
  useFrame(()=>{
    mesh.current.rotation.x+=0.01;
    mesh.current.rotation.y+=0.01;
    mesh.current.rotation.z+=0.01;
  });

  return (<mesh ref={mesh}>
    <boxBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[2,2,2]}/>
    <meshStandardMaterial {...props} />
  </mesh>);
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <Canvas>
      <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
      <spotLight position={[10, 10, 10]} angle={0.15} penumbra={1} />
      <pointLight position={[-10, -10, -10]} />
      <Suspense fallback={null}>
        <Box />
      </Suspense>
    </Canvas>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

There is no issue with import and any apparent error in browser console. But, the ultimate result is no image is shown as texture.
[image]
Can someone point me the direction to the error please?

Answer (score 1):

*Sorry to answer this so late, I hope you were able to fix this yourself.*

Anyway, I can see where you have gone wrong. Remember the Object being sent to the component will be deconstructed and the property names should tie in directly to the props.

For instance, if you look at your code you'd be expecting the deconstructed output to look something like this (which is invalid):

```js
<meshStandardMaterial texture_1={Object} />
```

The reason why this is invalid is that the prop `texture_1` is non-existent and what you really want is the prop `map`.

I see you've implicitly tried to define each side, so I'm going to assume you want to change each side later on, this solution should be what you want:

```js
function Box() {
  const textures = useTexture({
    img1,
    img1,
    img1,
    img1,
    img1,
    img1
  });
  const mesh = useRef();
  useFrame(() => {
    mesh.current.rotation.x += 0.01;
    mesh.current.rotation.y += 0.01;
    mesh.current.rotation.z += 0.01;
  });

  return (<mesh ref={mesh}>
    <boxBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[2, 2, 2]} />
    {textures.map((texture, idx) =>
      <meshBasicMaterial key={texture.id} attach={`material-${idx}`} map={texture} />
    )}
  </mesh>);
}
```

All I did was avoid making properties that didn't exist in the `useTexture` function. And made it loop over textures instead of relying on a deconstructed Object.

*Hope this helps*

---

If you want a simplified example take this Dice I made:

```js
function Dice() {
  const textures = useTexture({
    DiceSideOne,
    DiceSideTwo,
    DiceSideThree,
    DiceSideFour,
    DiceSideFive,
    DiceSideSix
  });

  return (<mesh>
    <boxBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[2, 2, 2]} />
    {textures.map((texture, idx) =>
      <meshBasicMaterial key={texture.id} attach={`material-${idx}`} map={texture} />
    )}
  </mesh>);
}
```